# Nested ul li navigation

Tags: php

So the result should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="url">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="url">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="url">Subitem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="url">Subitem 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="url">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

MySQL Database:

```
id | value     | url | parent
---+-----------+-----+-------
1  | Item 1    | 1   | 0
2  | Item 2    | 2   | 0
3  | Subitem 3 | 3   | 2
4  | Subitem 4 | 4   | 2
5  | Item 5    | 5   | 0
```

And the url comes from another MySQL table:

```
id | url
---+----
1  | url
2  | url
3  | url
4  | url
5  | url
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Try creating the hierarchy of that one database table as a php array first. Then later you can focus on transforming that into a nested list with the urls.

Answer (score 0):

First get the rows that has no parent (where parent=0) and loop them

```
foreach($parents as $row) {
echo '<li><a href="url">Item 2</a>';

//here get the items whose parent is $row['parent']
if(count($childs)>0) echo '<ul>';
foreach($childs as $child_row) {
echo '<li><a href="url">Subitem 1</a></li>';
}
if(count($childs)>0) echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
}
```